# How to align numbers in enumerate environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate, enumitem

I have the following code which produces the document below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0em}

\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep,label=\arabic*)}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \blindtext
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
        \item \blindtext
        \item \blindtext
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to have the item labels aligned with the left-hand side of the text in the paragraph above it - i.e. I would like the "1)" label to move to the left slightly, and the "a)" label should move left by the same amount, so it is aligned with the text under item 1.

I've tried adding the `leftmargin=\parindent` option in the `\setlist`, but this pushed the labels too far left (behind the left margin).

**Edit**

A possible solution, provided by Bernard in the comments below, is to use the `wide=0pt` key.  This produces the following result:

[image]

The problem I have with this is now the labels are aligned inside the rest of the paragraph (text appears directly below the label, which is not quite what I wanted).

Comment: Add the `[wide=0pt]` key.

Comment: That's a good start, thank you.  However, the "1)" label is now inside the paragraph, which I don't really want.

Comment: What do you mean with ‘inside the paragraph’?

Comment: See edited question

Comment: do you really set your main text with parindent and parskip both zero? how can the reader see a new paragraph?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I agree in an extended essay you'd need at least one of the two to see the paragraphs clearly, but I'm making some personal lecture notes, where each line rarely lasts more than one line, so I find it better to remove all indentation/spacing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0em}

\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep,label=\arabic*),wide = 0pt, leftmargin = *}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \blindtext
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
        \item \blindtext
        \item \blindtext
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]